# Interactive Quiz using ppt

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I posted a rubbish question about this before and have gone away and done some work on it to re-ask. Basically I've made a ppt quiz that counts how many correct and incorrect answers a person has given. It then feeds this information back to the user at the end. However what I want to happen now is I want the results to be stored so that I can go back in and see how each user has performed in the quiz. Ideally I would like it to work over 6 networked computers storing all the quiz results in one place. But if need be I can just take a file from each of the 6 computers.

My code so far looks like this:

```
Dim username As String
Dim numberCorrect As Integer
Dim numberWrong As Integer

Sub YourName()
username = InputBox(prompt:="Type your Name")
MsgBox " Get Ready to begin " + username, vbApplicationModal, " Orange 1C Book 7"
End Sub

Sub correct()
numberCorrect = numberCorrect + 1
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub incorrect()
numberWrong = numberWrong + 1
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub Start()
numberCorrect = 0
numberWrong = 0
YourName
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub Results()
MsgBox "Well done " & username & " You got " & numberCorrect & " out of " & numberCorrect + numberWrong, vbApplicationModal, "Orange 1C Book 7"

End Sub'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Not sure where to begin with the next step.

Comment: I think I asked you under the other (deleted?) question if you would be happy with saving your results in txt files? And when is the closing moment of the quiz, when user closes it (presentation) or at the moment of running `Resulta` sub as presented?

Comment: The quiz isn't currently set to close. I teach 5 year olds and was hoping I could leave it open so it would simply reset at the end of the quiz allowing for the quiz to be left on the class laptops and children to take turns taking the quiz. I would be happy with txt. I just need some way of being able to look back at the end of a lesson and see which children need more support and which are ready to be moved further on.

Comment: I suppose the closing point would be upon running sub results but I would want the physical presentation to remain open to make it as simple as possible for the kids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes one option for you... But some explanation first. This code will create TXT file. Each time someone will reach `Results` macro it will add results to the file. So, one file will keep all the results until you don't delete them (or the file). Therefore I've added separation line and date/time information for you to easily find appropriate results.

```
Sub Save_Results_To_Txt()

    'set file results location to activepresentation path
    'or could be changed to any path string
    Dim strWhere As String
        strWhere = ActivePresentation.Path
    'let's set name of the file separately
    Dim strName As String
        strName = "\results.txt"

    Dim ff As Long
    ff = FreeFile

    Open strWhere & strName For Append As #ff

    Write #ff, Now & vbTab & username
    Write #ff, numberCorrect & vbTab & vbTab & numberWrong
    Write #ff, String(30, "-")

    Close #ff

End Sub
```

You need to add `Save_Results_To_Txt` to your `Results` sub, possibly before `MsgBox` line.

Your results.txt file will look like:

```
"2013-04-25 16:11:05    Tom"
"10     11"
"------------------------------"
"2013-04-25 16:11:23    Mark"
"11     10"
"------------------------------"
```

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you so much for your help. Just one quick question. If I saved this all on a shared drive would each computer using the program be able to save to this same file?

Comment: Dealing with several computers writing to the same file at the same time might be more trouble than it's worth. You could instead change strWhere to the path to a folder on the shared drive and strName to Environ("COMPUTERNAME") & ".TXT"  which'd give you one file per computer, written to the shared drive; name of the file would be the same as the computer's name.

Comment: @user2165631, to be precise, you could encounter a problem if two children at the same moment will try to finish their quizes. But, let's assume that you have good local network and saving will take 0.01 sec. So, you need to think how big is the possibility that 2 children will finish at the same moment which time length is 0.01 sec? in my opinion possibility equals zero. But, Steve ideas is absolutely good one.

Comment: THank you, sorry completely forgot to mark it as answered. You've been really helpful thank you.