# Moving user input data from Word to excel (macros)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, plaintext

I created a form where the user rates the frequency of a certain event (always, sometimes, rarely, never, N/A) by clicking radio buttons displayed in a table.  The radio buttons are weighted, so if the user selects always, the value for that number of the question is 4 (sometimes = 3, etc.).  I need to take the results from the survey and put it into an excel document that averages the results from many surveys.  Currently I have a text box that prints the numbers st the end of the survey and I copy and paste them into my excel document but I would like to find a better way to do this.  Ideally if I could create a separate plain text document with word containing just the number results from the survey that can be imported into excel that would be perfect.  Below is a sample of my code: how the radio buttons are calculated and how they are printed

```
Private Sub RadioButtonyj_Click()
    If RadioButtonyj.Value = True Then

        num33 = 2
    UpdateRating
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub RadioButtonnj_Click()
    If RadioButtonnj.Value = True Then


        num33 = 1
    UpdateRating
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub RadioButtonnj1_Click()
    If RadioButtonnj1.Value = True Then


        num33 = 0
    UpdateRating
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateRating()
TextBox2.Text = num1 & vbNewLine & num2 & vbNewLine & _
num3 & vbNewLine & num4 & vbNewLine & _
num5 & vbNewLine & num6 & vbNewLine & _
num7 & vbNewLine & num8 & vbNewLine & num9 & vbNewLine & num10 & vbNewLine & num11 _
& vbNewLine & num12 & vbNewLine & num13 & vbNewLine & num14 & vbNewLine _
& num15 & vbNewLine & num16 & vbNewLine & num17 & vbNewLine & num18 & vbNewLine & num19             & vbNewLine _
& num20 & vbNewLine & num21 & vbNewLine & num22 & vbNewLine & num23 & vbNewLine _
& num24 & vbNewLine & num25 & vbNewLine & num26 & vbNewLine & num27 & vbNewLine & num28         &     vbNewLine _
& num29 & vbNewLine & num30 & vbNewLine & num31 & vbNewLine & num32 & vbNewLine & num33
End Sub

Dim FS As FileSystemObject
Set FS = New FileSystemObject


Dim MyFile As TextStream
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName.txt")
MyFile.Write num1 & vbNewLine & num2 & vbNewLine & _
num3 & vbNewLine & num4 & vbNewLine & _
num5 & vbNewLine & num6 & vbNewLine & _
num7 & vbNewLine & num8 & vbNewLine & num9 & vbNewLine & num10 & vbNewLine & num11 _
& vbNewLine & num12 & vbNewLine & num13 & vbNewLine & num14 & vbNewLine _
& num15 & vbNewLine & num16 & vbNewLine & num17 & vbNewLine & num18 & vbNewLine & num19 & vbNewLine _
& num20 & vbNewLine & num21 & vbNewLine & num22 & vbNewLine & num23 & vbNewLine _
& num24 & vbNewLine & num25 & vbNewLine & num26 & vbNewLine & num27 & vbNewLine & num28 & vbNewLine _
& num29 & vbNewLine & num30 & vbNewLine & num31 & vbNewLine & num32 & vbNewLine & num33




If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName2.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName2.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName3.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName3.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName4.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName4.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName5.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName5.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName6.txt")
End If


If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName6.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName7.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName7.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName8.txt")
End If


If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName8.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName9.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName9.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName10.txt")
End If


If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName10.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName11.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName11.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName12.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName12.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName13.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName13.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName14.txt")
End If

If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName14.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName15.txt")
End If


If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName15.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName16.txt")
End If


If FS.FileExists("C:\Folder\FileName16.txt") Then
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName17.txt")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you could try to explore [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214395/interactive-quiz-using-ppt/16217185#16217185). There was a quiz made in PowerPoint with results exported to text file which you could do in similar way.

Comment: @KazJaw This seems like it would be perfect.  I tried adding it to my document and I'm not sure what else I have to change for it to function with my results.  I just put strWhere=[information I have stored in textbox2 above]

Comment: you missed something... if you want to add some code add it to your question, not to comment...

Comment: Sorry about that.  I modified my code above

Answer (score 0):

To open and operate excel via VBA inside Word, got to the VBA editor:

```
Tools > References... > add Microsoft Excel <some version> Object Library
```

Just as there is already a corresponding `Microsoft Word <some version> Object Library` already referenced together with a `Microsoft Office <some version> Object Library` and some others.

Then you will be able to use excel objects in code, such as:

```
Dim ExApp as Excel.Application
Set ExApp = new Excel.Application

'Workbooks represent excel files
Dim MyBook as Workbook
Set MyBook = ExApp.Workbooks.Open(filename) 'or .Add and other options

'Worksheets represente excel sheets
Dim MySheet as Worksheet
Set MySheet = MyBook.Worksheets(some name or index)

'Ranges represent cells or a range of cells
Dim MyCell as Excel.Range 
Set MyCell = MySheet.Range("A1") 'or .Cells(1,1) and others

'Notice that excel application will remain invisible until you do this
ExApp.Visible = true
```

For a more detailed answer on importing some data from word to excel, go to this:
[Importing specific data from a Word to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919535/importing-specific-data-from-a-word-to-excel/16919784#16919784)

To create a plain text file, go and add reference to:

```
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime
```

That will allow you to work with `FileSystemObject`, `File`, `Folder` and others.
The `FileSystemObject` has a `CreateTextFile` method that will help you do that.

```
Dim FS as FileSystemObject
Set FS = new FileSystemObject

Dim MyFile As TextStream
Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\FileName.txt")
```

Then you can go further in the methods to add lines and to save it.

To check if a file exists and don't overwrite it, do the following loop:

```
Dim FS As FileSystemObject
Dim MyFile As TextStream
Dim i As Integer
Dim FilePrefix As String, FileName As String, Extension As String

FilePrefix = "C:\Folder\FileName"
Extension = ".txt"
i = 1

FileName = FilePrefix & Trim(Str(i)) & Extension
Do While (FS.FileExists(FileName))
    i = i + 1
    FileName = FilePrefix & Trim(Str(i)) & Extension
Loop

Set MyFile = FS.CreateTextFile(FileName)

'Do the writings
```

Notice that you don't have to create all files, just create the new one after you've checked existance. And do the writings only after seting `MyFile`

Comment: I think it would be better create a .txt file because the user is supposed to send us the results so we can generate a full report using this information.  The only problem with this method is how would the user be able to take the survey multiple times without overwriting the results?

Comment: The `FileSystemObject` also has a `FileExists` method to check if a file already exists. If so, you can give it another name, like `filename2`, and keep testing in a loop. If `Filename2` exists, go `filename3` and so on.

Comment: thanks for your help.  The code I added creates all of the files at once but only writes the the first one.  How would I modify this?